# Get the list of mail chimp subscribers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mailchimp

I am working on a simple rails rails app and i have so many subscribers in my mail mailchimp account and i want to get my all subscribers and send the a mail from my rails app. How do i get my subscribers emails in an array.

my code sample is below

```
def send_now
    @news_letter = NewsLetter.find(params[:id])  
      gb = Gibbon::API.new("xxx")
      members = gb.lists.members({:id => 'xxx'})
      #for each goes here to send the mail   
      redirect_to manage_news_letter_path(@news_letter), notice: "Sent news Letter"        
  end
```

I can get the list of subscribers but how can i split out their email into a for_each method in rails cos the format is i in a hash. any help thanks.

example output is below

{"email"=>"xx@xx.com", "id"=>"xx", "euid"=>"xx", "email_type"=>"html", "ip_signup"=>nil, "timestamp_signup"=>nil, "ip_opt"=>"208.68.37.172", "timestamp_opt"=>"2014-02-21 10:38:20", "member_rating"=>2, "info_changed"=>"2014-02-21 10:38:20", "web_id"=>xx, "leid"=>xx, "language"=>nil, "list_id"=>"xx", "list_name"=>"Blanckdigital website List", "merges"=>{"EMAIL"=>"xx@xx.com", "FNAME"=>"", "LNAME"=>""}, "status"=>"subscribed", "timestamp"=>"2014-02-21 10:38:20", "is_gmonkey"=>false, "lists"=>[], "geo"=>[], "clients"=>[], "static_segments"=>[], "notes"=>[]}

what i want is is just the email xx@xx.com alone for each of the subscribers

Comment: Please share an example of hash(input) and expected output.

Comment: i have updated it to include the output

Comment: Thanks. One quick question, the example shown here only shows a single record, if multiple records then how would your hash look like (comma separated)?

Comment: yes. i just noticed it also comes with the total data also